# Where can I see or manage the hidden Hyper-V VMs created by WSL2 or certain other applications?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Two applications in specific, [Windows Subsystem for Linux 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions) and [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) (an Android emulator) explicitly leverage Hyper-V, and require the windows feature to be enabled on the system you're running it on.

**WSL2** acts like a VM in most ways that matter, it has its own network interface and requires [certain hoops to jump through](https://www.williamjbowman.com/blog/2020/04/25/running-a-public-server-from-wsl-2/) to expose a service listening in the VM to the outside world.

**Bluestacks** explicitly mentions VM creation during its setup process.

I'd expect to be able to look at and poke around these VMs using the Hyper-V manager application like any other.. yet there are none listed:

[image: Hyper-V Manager Screenshot]
Ignore the "New Virtual Machine", that is something manually created by me months before messing around with either of these apps - but it also proves that Hyper-V manager can see VMs correctly.

The fact that both of these applications are running "hidden" VMs leads me to believe that the cause of their invisibility in the manager is the same.

I am on Windows 10 b19041, and my user has administrator rights. Running Hyper-V manager as administrator via the right-click menu has no effect.

Where can I find the information for these "hidden" VMs and work with them using Hyper-V's tools?

Comment: Could you perhaps split this into two questions? WSL is a Microsoft product, while Bluestacks is a 3rd party product. The ways and methods they hide their source VMs will differ.

Comment: The question is about working with hidden VMs, not the specific applications. It doesn't make intuitive sense that there are multiple ways of hiding VMs from the management tools. Did you seriously VTC this as unclear *because specific examples were given*?

Comment: Hopefully this partially answers the question: https://superuser.com/a/1692667/352118

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hcsdiag list` will show the WSL VM; it will also show things like the Windows Sandbox VM and the Edge application guard VM.

More information:

- [Host Compute System Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/api/hcs/overview)
- [Introducing the Host Compute Service (HCS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20170127-introducing-the-host-compute-service-hcs)

Comment: Good information (that I've been wondering about for a while), and a *great* first answer.