# What part of Hyper-V is used by WSL2?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, wsl2

I know that WSL2 doesn't use the whole VM, it just uses the part of Windows' Hyper-V, so it is not so resource-demanding, am I right? But I can't find the exact information about how Hyper-V is used by WSL2. Microsoft Docs says that "WSL is more lightweight than real VM" and nothing more.

So my question is:
What part of Hyper-V is used by WSL2 and HOW it is used?
Or if WSL2 doesn't use Hyper-V at all, how does it run Linux kernel then?

Comment: The 2 things are different beasts. Hyper-V is a Virtual Machine app and runs complete machines. WSL is a variant that allows Linux commands in Windows. Same base, different things for different purposes.

Comment: @John - Your description of WSL only applies to WSL1, WSL2 runs the actual Linux kernel, within a small virtual machine. Only one leverages virtualization.

Comment: Thanks. I was happy with WSL 1.  WSL 2 still appears to be a work in progress and I am still working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To support WSL2, Hyper-V has been split up in Windows 10.

The hypervisor – known as the "Virtual Machine Platform" is available
on all Windows versions and is the minimum that is required to run WSL
as a light-weight virtual machine that is tightly integrated with
the host.

Hyper-V Manager is now a distinct Windows feature that is used for running
full-featured virtual machines whose integration with the host is
limited. It is not available on Windows Home.

Comment: Based on this, could we turn off Hyper-V manger and still be able to run a fully isolated Linux guest VM (or even a Windows VM) configured to use the KVM hypervisor?