# How to check WSL2's virtual machine status?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, wsl2

Per [the WSL documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions), WSL2 is a virtual machine on Hyper-V. However, this VM's status is not visible from Hyper-V Manager.

How can I check WSL2's virtual machine status?  For instance:

- If it's running or not?
- CPU being consumed?
- RAM being consumed?

Comment: `hcsdiag list` See https://superuser.com/a/1761003/1761216 for bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this VM's status is not visible from Hyper-V Manager.

And as an aside, I'd still love to know the mechanism they use to hide it.  BlueStacks apparently does the same thing according to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1616181/1210833) (and I've confirmed).

> How to check WSL2's virtual machine status?

Most of this will be found under the `vmmem` (under existing WSL2 releases) or `vmmemWSL` (for WSL2 Preview and presumably future releases) process.

> If it's running or not?

The presence of `vmmem`/`vmmemWSL` in the process list is, in my experience, always an indicator of the WSL2 VM running or not.

You can see this process appear (if it wasn't running already) when you start a WSL2 distribution.  And it will end when either:

- `wsl --shutdown` is executed.
- Or when both timers discussed in WSL Discussion [#8659](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/8659) have expired.

Note that it's also possible to see the startup and shutdown messages in the Event Viewer if you go digging.

> CPU being consumed?

`Get-Process vmmem` (or `vmmemWSL`) from an Administrative PowerShell (CPU info requires Admin).  I haven't tested this myself, so it would be interesting to get confirmation on how accurate this appears based on, perhaps, some profiling within the WSL2 distribution and without.

> RAM being consumed?

Task Manager or `Get-Process vmmem` (or `vmmemWSL`).

Also a small amount from `vmwp.exe` (the "Virtual Machine Worker Process").

Note that just *enabling* WSL2 via the Virtual Machine Platform (and/or Hyper-V) will [consume appropriately 1GB of memory](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/wo6729/the_hidden_costs_of_wsl2_memory_usage/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that isn't reported elsewhere.  This is simply the overhead of having Hyper-V functionality enabled in the first place, whether or not a VM is currently running.

Also note that this is specifically, as you requested, the VM.  There is also, of course, some memory consumed by other supporting processes such as the terminal and the LxssManager itself.

Comment: Thanks. Under C: root, I " dir /s \*vmmem\*". But I hit "File Not Found". Where is vmmem.exe located?

Comment: @kgflying Oops - I made a bad assumption that `vmmem` was a process started by the `vmmem.exe` executable, but it's not.  Without having traced everything out at this point, I believe it's coming from `C:\Windows\System32\vmpmem.dll`, which is called from (again, I believe) `vmwp.exe` in the same directory.